# Node js error when parsing a text file with transform stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, stream

I need to parse a text file on Node js server. The text file consists of the header and a list of items, all on separate lines. I do a request, then I pipe the response to the parser stream. I need to extract the time from the header. The problem is that sometimes the header variable gets appended with some info from the middle of the file. If i console.log it, it looks something like this:

```
HEADER
MIDDLE_OF_THE_FILE_STUFF
```

The strangest thing is that it doen't happen all the time. Only sometimes. And the middle of the file stuff is appended from the same place in the file every time. And I tried doing `header.substring(0,len)` but it only cuts the header itself, no the MIDDLE_OF_THE_FILE_STUFF.

Here's the code:

```
parser._transform = function(chunk,encoding,done){
    var time = {};
    var data = chunk.toString();
    lines = data.split('\n');

    header = (lines[0]);

    var regEx = /[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/;

    var m = regEx.exec(header);
    var splitTime = m[0].split(':');
    time = {
        hours:splitTime[0],
        minutes:splitTime[1]
    }
    console.log(time);
    var pushjson = JSON.stringify(time, null, 2);
    this.push(pushjson);
    done();


}

request
    .get('url')
    .on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err)
    })
    .pipe(parser)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('result.json'))
```

I've been struggling with this for quite some time and I can't find posts with the same error anywhere. I think I just might not understand how transofrm stream works completely. So, please help.

Comment: Can you post the input file you are using so I can run it from my computer?

Comment: @DanielJacobson http://maps.weather.gov.hk/r4/input_files/latestReadings_AWS1

Comment: Your `_transform` function can be called any number of times, with more chunks, depending on the size of the input. There doesn't seem to be anything there to stop emitting output after the first call.

Comment: Are you using the request module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NPM split module to parse streams line by line, I use this module in my streams. Heres the code in it's entirety.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var parser = new stream.Transform({
objectMode: true
});
var request = require('request');
var split = require('split');
var fs = require('fs');

var currLine = 1;
var header;

parser._transform = function(line, encoding, done) {
    var time = {};
    if (currLine === 1) {
        header = line;
        console.log(header);
        var regEx = /[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/;

        var m = regEx.exec(header);
        var splitTime = m[0].split(':');
        time = {
            hours: splitTime[0],
            minutes: splitTime[1]
        };
        console.log(time);
        var pushjson = JSON.stringify(time, null, 2);
        this.push(pushjson);
    }
    currLine++;
    done();
};

request
    .get('http://maps.weather.gov.hk/r4/input_files/latestReadings_AWS1')
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }).
pipe(split()).pipe(parser)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('result.json'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I don't quite get how it works. Does split make sure that lines are consistent?

Comment: Glad to help. Yes it does. "Break[s] up a stream and reassemble it so that each line is a chunk." https://www.npmjs.com/package/split